# How to display related attribute and values properly with ajax?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

Here based on the class selected I want to display it's related attributes on the select option with ajax and jquery and on the side of select option there is a input field for attribute's related values.

After selecting class it should displays related attributes and the related attribute's related values. The error while calling the `Attribute` function is
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Attributes is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange`

**EDIT:** I was getting the above error was because of syntax mismatch after solving this the above error is also gone.
But now the error is like this.

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
"GET /product/ajax/Attribute?class_id=2 HTTP/1.1" 500 83956
```

views.py

```
class_id = request.GET.get('class_id')
qs = Attribute.objects.filter(class=class_id)
attribute_data = []
attribute_data_values = []

for obj in qs:
    attribute_data.append(obj.attribute)
    attribute_data_values.append(obj.attribute.attributevalues_set.all())

data = serializers.serialize('json', attribute_data)
print(data)
values = serializers.serialize('json', attribute_data_values)
print(values)

response_data = {
    'attribute': data,
    'values': values
}

return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': response_data}))
```

the script function is called from here.

```
self.fields['class'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Class.objects.all(),widget=forms.Select(attrs = {'onchange': "Attributes(this.value);"}))
```

html

```
<td><select class="form-control attribute-options" name="name" type="text">
       {% for attribute in attributes %}
        <option value="{{attribute.pk}}">{{attribute.name}}</option>
       {% endfor %}
   </select></td>
<td><input class="form-control attribute-input" name="value" type="text"></td>
```

script(main problem is here)

```
 function Attributes(value){
      $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "get_attribute" %}',

        data:{
          'class_id' : value,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
//          console.log(response.data.attribute)

            var attribute = response.data.attribute;
            var values = response.data.values;
            console.log('values', values)
            data = $.parseJSON(attribute);
            values_data = $.parseJSON(values);
            array_values = []
            $.each(data, function (index, el) {
                var attributeName = el.fields.name;
                var id = index
                $(".attribute-options").append("<option value=" + attributeName + ">" + attributeName + "</option>");

            })
             $.each(data, function (index, el) {
                var value = el.fields.name;
                array_values.push(value);
                $(".attribute-input").val(array_values);

            })
        });
    }
```

Comment: why you have `type="text"` in your select-box ? Also , how your function gets called ? I am not seeing any `onchange=".."` under your select-tag and not sure what you are doing here `$(".attribute-input").val(array_values);` this will replace content everytime you loop .

Comment: @Swati i am a beginner in ajax/jquery so can you suggest what changes should i have to made here ?

Comment: What do you mean by `related attribute's related values are not displaying..` ? Can you please elaborate ? Also you are getting error function not defined .but you are saying `displays related attributes correctly ..` ?

Comment: when this function is called then I want to display attributes and it's values(which are returned by django view) in the `attribute-options` and `attribute-input` class respectively at a time. @Swati

Comment: can you add `op` of `response` ? Also there is only one input box with class `attribute-input` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222601/discussion-between-swati-and-d-p).